# Forçar update no lado do cliente após atualização do site

Tags: javascript, css, html5, atualização

O cenário do meu problema é o seguinte, possuo um website que foi atualizado, porém alguns clientes estão reportando que a atualização não foi feita para eles, que ainda estão no modelo antigo do site (provavelmente pela persistência do *cache*).

Já fiz diversas atualizações e nunca tive esse problema. Não sei se foi o tamanho da atualização (basicamente um re-trabalho de todo o projeto) que está implicando nesse problema, mas não consigo fazer com que os usuários acessem a nova versão do site.

Sei que limpar o *cache*, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> podem ajudar, mas, inviável...

Já faço uso da prática de versão nos arquivos, por exemplo:

```
scr="meuscript.js?v=0123456"

href="meuestilo.css?v=0123456"
```

Também utilizo algumas tags no HTML, como:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Mas nada surtiu o efeito desejado. Confesso que é uma área que não possuo muita experiência e conhecimento. Então, o que eu poderia fazer para obter o resultado desejado? Ou seja, forçar a atualização da página (ou de *cache*) no lado do cliente?

Comment: um parametro dummie na url faz isso...

Comment: @andrepaulo algum exemplo?

Comment: se sua url nao tem nenhum parametro `?a=1` por ex... se tiver `&a=1` ve se te ajuda... mas a cada vez que voce quiser atualizada o numero muda, ou o parametro muda... cada url diferente faz com que o browser atualize

Comment: @andrepaulo não foi o caso... Continua a mesma coisa.

Comment: Pergunta: você inseriu as *tags* de controle de cache antes ou depois do problema aparecer? Se foi depois, seria necessário a limpeza do cache para atualizá-los para a versão com essas tags.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss comecei a utilizar a partir dessa atualização. Ou seja, na versão anterior não existia e nessa existe. Mas mesmo assim, isso não faria com que o arquivo fosse lido diferente?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Algo que vi nessa [resposta do SOEng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-to-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers)

Pegando a parte que de fato interessa:

*Quando esses valores são providos através dos headers das respostas das requisições, ele têm precedência sobre as tags `<meta>`. alguns servidores mandam valores default, então é aconselhável que seja enviado junto à resposta os headers explicitamente.*

Você consegue verificar o que está vindo utilizando o DevTools, indo na aba `Network` > clicando sobre a requisição da sua pagina > verifique o header `Cache-Control` na seção `Response Headers` da aba `Headers` do painel lateral.

**Utilizando PHP:**

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
header("Expires: 0"); // Proxies.
```

**Utilizando Java Servlet**, ou **Node.js:**

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
response.setHeader("Expires", "0"); // Proxies.
```

**Utilizando ASP.NET-MVC**

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);  // HTTP 1.1.
Response.Cache.AppendCacheExtension("no-store, must-revalidate");
Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
Response.AppendHeader("Expires", "0"); // Proxies.
```

**Utilizando ASP.NET:**

```
Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
Response.AppendHeader("Expires", "0"); // Proxies.
```

**Utilizando ASP:**

```
Response.addHeader "Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" ' HTTP 1.1.
Response.addHeader "Pragma", "no-cache" ' HTTP 1.0.
Response.addHeader "Expires", "0" ' Proxies.
```

Comment: Pois então, eu já tentei isso e não adiantou. Na minha pergunta eu informo que já tentei isso.

Comment: com todos os contents? do cache control?

Comment: outra coisa mencionada é enviar no response esses dados, qual linguagem server voce esta usando?

Comment: Estou usando PHP e também estou tentando testar aqueles parâmetros extras (não havia notado)

Comment: e ai? deu certo man? enviando os headers na resposta?

Comment: Estou testando.. É algo difícil de testar em ambiente real de uso, pois preciso verificar em outros computadores, etc.. Mas a princípio sim! Uma coisa que me deixou em dúvida também foi o comentário do Anderson na pergunta. Sabes se isso pode interferir?

Comment: a pergunta dele é resolvida dessa forma, uma vez que quando voce manda os headers pelo response ele vai ter precendencia sobre as meta tags.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, uma solução bem simples é renomear os arquivos HTML/CSS/JS que foram modificados (e claro, mudar onde também são chamados), assim o browser não reconhece nada em cache e faz o carregamento dos arquivos frescos.

Answer (score -1):

Um método para forçar o navegador a limpar o cache é o app cache do HTML5. 
Você cria um arquivo de Manifesto onde escreve o que deve ser mantido em cache e o que não deve ser cacheado.

**SEMPRE** que o arquivo de manifesto for atualizado, os recursos serão **ATUALIZADOS obrigatoriamente**. 
(não se esqueça de limpar o tanto de meta tag que você usou sobre cache) 
um exemplo de manifest:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2012-02-21 v1.0.0
/theme.css #em cache
/logo.gif # em cache
/main.js # em cache

NETWORK:
login.asp #nunca será mantido em cache

FALLBACK:
/html/ /offline.html
```

Dê uma olhada se te ajuda:

http://www.escolaw3.com/tutoriais/html/html5-cache-app

Comment: Eu li a respeito. Mas também vi que não é mais recomendado seu uso devido a descontinuidade de suporte. [Referência](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache). Posso estar enganado, mas não seria a mesma coisa que você recomendou?

Comment: Bem, você deve ter lido pelo mozilla ne?
dê uma olhada nesse texto:

http://www.andygup.net/application-cache-is-not-gone-oh-my-or-is-it/

As coisas não são bem assim, e cache de aplicação, no mínimo, ainda será mantida pelos próximos anos... 
Pode usar sem medo, ele faz parte do HTML5, provavelmente quando o removerem seu site já terá sido refeito (novamente)