# Cache - Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, cache

Tenho uma aplicação angularjs(1.x.x)/php que a cada atualização de versão, alguns usuários que usam Firefox na última versão, são obrigados a executar o CTRL+SHIFT+R para limpar o cache e obter a versão atualizada da aplicação.
Qual seria a maneira ideal do browser checar se está no último branch e em caso negativo, recarregar/ limpar os caches automaticamente?

A idéia é saber se existe alguma maneira do próprio angular verifica se houve ou não modificação nos arquivos JS.

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/192256/for%C3%A7ar-update-no-lado-do-cliente-ap%C3%B3s-atualiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-site

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Forçar update no lado do cliente após atualização do site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/192256/for%c3%a7ar-update-no-lado-do-cliente-ap%c3%b3s-atualiza%c3%a7%c3%a3o-do-site)